Posting data json by clicking a button
I try to do a simple function that when I click on 'A button' in GUI's code, it send JSON data to the local host. The local host still receives the data even though the Pycharm GUI does not launch when I click "run." This is my code:
   import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json

class handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()

        message = "Hello, World! Here is a GET response"
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','application/json')
        self.end_headers()

        with open("input.json", "r") as f:
            file_data = f.read()
            json_data = json.dumps(file_data)

        self.wfile.write(bytes(json_data, "utf8"))

with HTTPServer(('', 8000), handler) as server:
    server.serve_forever()

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x500')
window.title('Event Bindding')

text = tk.Text(window)
text.pack()

button = ttk.Button(window, text='A button')
button.pack()

window.bind('<a>', lambda event: print( handler.do_POST()))

window.mainloop()

I try to seprate each function to make sure that each code work.

Clicking the "A button" does nothing because the command option is not set.  Also there is no code on sending JSON data to the local host.

Both the server and the tkinter mainloop run forever and block each other. Look for tutorials on how to do this with threading, or some sample applications on GitHub.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
